# document.getElementByTag

Tags: objective-c, ios4, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I already used document.getElementById, but it does not work any more. I want to get the value of 0,01€ but I can not. I want to save it in my `NSString *price` but how.
The HTML code is

```
<tr class="price">
<td>0,01</td>
<td>EUR</td>
```

My idea was

```
NSString *price = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('price.td').innerText;"];
```

Comment: the tag is supposed to be TR and your only chance to achieve such a result in javascript is to enumerate all of them looking for the attribute class=='price' or use some advanced JQuery expression to select a particular node matching the criteria. My experience tells that you may be luckier if you start from the table. Your question is not detailed enough to really help you and I'm sure you're approaching the problem in a wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tagName in this case is 'td' not 'price.td', but if you run `document.getElementsByTagName('id')` you will get all the table cells in the page which is probably not what you want.

If the page has jQuery loaded in it you can use `jQuery('.price td:first').text()` to get the price.

If it doesn't have jQuery but you have control of the page you can add a class to it (`<td class="my-price">12.44</td>`) and get it with `document.getElementsByClassName('my-price')[0].innerHTML`.

If you don't have control of the page and it doesn't have jQuery you will have to find the  'price' row and then get its 1-st cell by using `document.getElementsByClassName('my-price')[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: thanks for your help. You showed me the right way. Now I did it like this: NSString *price = [captcha stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerText;"];

Comment: I'm not even sure what that would do. I guess it will return the text in all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Also, a cleaner and more flexible approach is to use the Selectors API:

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/

```
document.querySelector('.price td:first').innerText
```